# how to combine left joins?

Tags: sql, ms-access

In MS Access 2007 query, how can I combine the following 2 queries?

```
SELECT Tests.Release, Testcases.TestCase, Tests.Result
FROM Tests LEFT JOIN Testcases ON Tests.TestCaseID=Testcases.ID;

SELECT Tests.Release, ResultEnums.Result
FROM Tests LEFT JOIN ResultEnums ON ResultEnums.ID=Tests.Result;
```

Thanks

Comment: Are data in `Testcases` related to `ResultEnums` in any way?

Comment: @Michael - Is the table `ResultEnums` parent to the `Tests` table?

Comment: @Thomas: `ResultEnums.ID` has relation to `Tests.Result`

Comment: @Michael: That relation is: `one Test - many ResultEnums` or `many Tests - one ResultEnum` ?

Comment: @Michael - What type of relation? For each `ResultEnums` row, can it be referenced multiple times in `Tests.Results`? It sounds like `ResultEnums` is the parent in that relation and if so, you can combine the two Left Joins into a single query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't test now but you surely need parenthesis:

```
SELECT Tests.Release
     , Testcases.TestCase
     , Tests.Result
     , ResultEnums.Result
FROM ( Tests 
       LEFT JOIN Testcases
         ON Tests.TestCaseID=Testcases.ID
     ) 
     LEFT JOIN ResultEnums
       ON ResultEnums.ID=Tests.Result 
;
```

or

```
SELECT Tests.Release
     , Testcases.TestCase
     , Tests.Result
     , ResultEnums.Result
FROM ( Tests 
       LEFT JOIN ResultEnums
         ON ResultEnums.ID=Tests.Result
     )
     LEFT JOIN Testcases
       ON Tests.TestCaseID=Testcases.ID
;
```

Answer (score 2):

Access has this craptastic "feature" which requires you pair your joins in parentheses:

```
Select Tests.Release, Testcases.TestCase, Tests.Result, ResultEnums.Result
From (Tests
    Left Join TestCases
        On TestCases.TestCaseID = Tests.TestCaseID)
    Left Join ResultEnums
        On ResultEnums.ID = Tests.Result
```

This type of query can produce some bad results depending on the schema. If for a given `Tests` row, multiple `TestCases` rows and multiple `ResultEnums` rows are returned, those rows will be combined via a cross product with each other. For example, if a given `Tests` row returned five `TestCases` rows and three `ResultEnums` rows, you will get 15 rows for that Tests row. However, if say `ResultEnums` is parent to the `Tests` table (thus for every `Tests` row, you would only get one `ResultEnums` value), then this should work fine.

Comment: +1 for the "*craptastic*". What bothers me more in Access is that you can't use INNER JOINs with LEFT JOINs (even with parenthesis!).

Comment: @ypercube - You can, but it's hokey. Once you get beyond about three or four tables, you almost have to assemble the joins in the QBE to see where it is going to put the parentheses. It's definitely an "experience".

Comment: I think you are allowed to have `a INNER JOIN (b LEFT JOIN c)` but not `a LEFT JOIN (b INNER JOIN c)`. Is that correct?

Comment: @ypercube  - I believe it is something like that. I'd have to open Access and try a few to remember which scenario it barfs on.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Tests.Release, Testcases.TestCase, Tests.Result, ResultEnums.Result
FROM Tests LEFT JOIN Testcases ON Tests.TestCaseID=Testcases.ID
LEFT JOIN ResultEnums ON ResultEnums.ID=Tests.Result;
```

**EDIT** I didn't test on Access, but in SQL Server you could do something akin to this.

Comment: This would be akin to a cross-join between Testcases and ResultEnums though, may or may not be what he wants.

Comment: This gives syntax error missing operator (of course corrected semicolumn).

Comment: @Lasse good point, might not be the best idea to actually combine it into one query.

Comment: The first query returns Tests.Result, which is relation to ResultEnums.ID. Now I need to get ResultEnums.Result, instead of its ID (which is happening on second query)

Comment: This cannot possibly work in Access/Jet/ACE, as the first semicolon terminates the SQL statement, and everything after that generates the "characters found after end of SQL statement" error message.

Comment: @David, good catch, I typo'd the first semicolon, updated now

Answer (score 0):

A very naive/simplified solution would be to simply `UNION ALL` them:

```
SELECT Tests.Release, Testcases.TestCase, Tests.Result
FROM Tests LEFT JOIN Testcases ON Tests.TestCaseID=Testcases.ID;

UNION ALL
SELECT Tests.Release, NULL, ResultEnums.Result
FROM Tests LEFT JOIN ResultEnums ON ResultEnums.ID=Tests.Result;
```

**edit:**  update for [comment here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5655535/how-to-combine-left-joins#comment-6451321)

I think this is what you want, the `Result` from the `ResultEnums` table, the `Release` from the `Tests` table, and the associated `TestCase` from the `Testcases` table, all `JOIN`ed on their keys:

```
SELECT
    re.Result
    ,t.Release
    ,tc.TestCase
FROM
    Tests t
    LEFT JOIN TestCases tc ON t.TestCaseID = tc.ID
    LEFT JOIN ResultEnums re ON re.ID = t.Result
```

Comment: This is giving completely wrong result... I've tried to explained what I am trying to do in previous answer.